meaning of "bet against" in this content
I would like someone to transform the sentence in bold into a plain English sentence for me to understand it better.
"I was fascinated by the American machine. If you've spent a bit of time in Europe and grown up in the 70s and 80s, it's fascinating. America is just something you want to try an understand the American economy and the American entreperneurs, not someone you ever want to bet against.
this "not someone you ever want to bet against",
does that mean "you don't want to bet on someone who will lose"?
thank you

It is a way to express the idea that America is a very strong country.

If you bet on America losing in a competition you will lose the bet.

You can bet on someone to win, or you can bet against someone to win — that is, you can bet that they won’t win. America will win, so don’t bet that it won’t (don’t bet against it) unless you want to lose your money.

To bet against someone or something is to bet that they (or it) will lose.
The saying expresses the view that the United States and its entrepreneurs are strong and capable.
